I want to creating a setup script to seed database in openiddict
I am a developer student and working on a openiddict project that is almost done. Before using it in production i want to seed the database in the proper production-ready way. In Openiddict samples, there is a note that the:
services.AddHostedService<Worker>(); should be replaced with a setup script.
I am thinking of using Azure Devops pipeline and cannot figure out what script to replace the services.AddHostedService<Worker>(); with to add the clients and scopes.
I cannot find a good example, and i have tried searching. Is it possible to use migration to seed the clients and scopes in openiddict? Or am i missing something?
